# Unable to Create Android Virtual device?

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device

While creating AVD ,after selecting the system image , i encountered the error vt-x is diabled in bios security settings.How to tackle this issue. Please provide possible solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Start your PC, press F2, go to the security option and enable VT technology and in some new BIOS, it called Virtual technology or Intel virtualization in the CPU setting option.. For more you can refer  to this  video
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=3irpIFya_lk
Hope this helps

Comment: i am using windows 8 , x64-based processor.So is this helpful for me

Comment: Did you try the solution ?? I think you will find the enable vt-x in intel virtualization in cpu setting... Even i use windows 8 x64.. It worked for me

Comment: yes i tried this.But it could not work. Please provide solution for this issue

Comment: Some system manufacturers do not provide this option under bios.. Whats your system brand and model

Comment: HP ,Intel Core i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz

Comment: Are you able to find advanced chipset settings in your bios??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120313/discussion-between-user-and-moulesh).

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following steps:
1.Start your system in boot mode
2.Go to BIOS setup utility(this may differ so you have to find the utility which corresponds to BIOS setup)
3.Go to security->BIOS update option
4.If it is already enabled,Keep it that way otherwise enable it
5.Start Android Studio
6.Go to AVD manager(you can find a small icon at the upper right side in the tools icon area)
7.Select the appropriate version 
It should be perfectly working now.